# Magento : Extract ALL Invoices of Orders at Once

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, invoice, print

I need to extract all invoice of orders from beginning, there are thousands of invoices.
Manually clicking PRINT and saving invoices in PDF is lot of work and time consuming.

Any way, to speed up and extract all invoice at once in folder and then download them all?